# How to hide a material button?

Tags: angular, angular-material, material-ui

I want to hide my Material button but it doesn't work.

My button is grey (**OK**):

```
<button mat-raised-button class="mat-primary" (click)="deleteClick()" [disabled]="data.createMode">
    <mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon>DELETE
</button>
```

My button is displayed (**OK isn't hidden**):

```
<button mat-raised-button class="mat-primary" (click)="deleteClick()" [hidden]="data.createMode">
    <mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon>DELETE
</button>
```

Comment: I guess that you do not want to use ngIf? As I see mat-button does not have hidden option https://material.angular.io/components/button/api

Comment: mat-button will be displayed as an html code, so as all html code can be REMOVED from DOM with *ngIf

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can hide your `mat-button` by these methods

**Method 1:**

```
<button mat-button [hidden]="true">Basic</button>
```

in scss file

```
[hidden] {
  display: none !important;
}
```

**Method 2:**

By using `*ngIf` which is recommended by @leopal

```
<button mat-raised-button class="mat-primary" (click)="deleteClick()" *ngIf="!data.createMode">
    <mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon>DELETE
</button>
```

**Method 3:**
By using Style, visibility will take his place on view but element will not be shown

```
<button mat-button [style.visibility]="true ? 'hidden': 'visible'">Basic</button>
```

or you can use `style.display`

```
<button mat-button [style.display]="true ? 'none': ''">Basic</button>
```

**Method 4:**

You can use `Class` property

```
<button mat-button [class.is-hidden]="true">Basic</button>
```

and in your scss file

```
.is-hidden {
      display: none;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<button mat-raised-button class="mat-primary" (click)="deleteClick()" *ngIf="!data.createMode">
    <mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon>DELETE
</button>
```

Comment: More comment to this answer should be better

Comment: actually is the same of the above answer. I just noticed now. And your answer should be the original :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no `hidden` attribute on `mat-button` directive as you can see on official [docs](https://material.angular.io/components/button/api).

You can go with the angular way though and use [ngIf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf) directive.

```
<button mat-raised-button class="mat-primary" (click)="deleteClick()" *ngIf="!data.createMode">
    <mat-icon>delete_forever</mat-icon>DELETE
</button>
```

Comment: Why did you copy/paste my answer? He just had to edit it.

Comment: Your answer contains just a code snippet. I provided an explanation for why the reported issue occurs and an alternative for achieving the desired result. Indeed the code snippet is the same but I think my answer clears things out.

Answer (score 0):

In angular you can choose to hide an element from the rendered html in 2 way, by removing it from the DOM with *ngIf or hide him with [hidden] attrubute, but will not be removed from the DOM only hided on the view, try alwaise to remove the element and not to hide it:

https://www.talkingdotnet.com/dont-use-hidden-attribute-angularjs-2/.

So just apply *ngIf, but be aware of what type of ChangeDetection are you using, if some other component can change the state of your *ngIf state, sometimes you need to go dirty and apply manually changeDetection.